# Lines of commented code changing the output layout in asp.net MVC 3!! Why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've an asp.net mvc3 project in c#. In one of the views 'Index.cshtml', I've a a number of consequent lines of code( jquery code ) which is commented, but when I run the application, this is causing the output layout/arrangement of the page to go haywire. When the commented code is deleted, it works fine. Why this peculiar behaviour? Anybody got any ideas?

link to the whole code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/85098448/Index.cshtml

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @MarkOreta: I've edited the question to include the commented code, thanks!

Comment: Could you post some more code showing what is around this?  Presumably this is in a <script> tag, so could you post the whole script tag?

Comment: @BuhBuh: following this, it is the script tag, but the whole thing is quite huge. I'll try though, thanks.

Comment: @BuhBuh: I've just pasted the link to the whole code, its quite long, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the very last line `});`

Comment: which function sir? first one or second?

Comment: the first line is commented as well, that was a typo. Do I still have to uncomment that?